# Logically group xml layout files in Android

Tags: android, layout

I have seen this question asked before, but from what I've seen the answers are all a couple of years old so I'm hoping the architecture has changed since then to allow this.

If it doesn't make sense for my project to have all of the layout files in res/layout is there some way for me to logically group related files? The obvious solution seems to be sub-directories, but unless things have changed (and I hope they have) it seems like this can't be done.

Are there any other alternatives to group my layout files?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think so it's any different now also with 4.4.2. As per my understanding you can't keep your layout files in any other place than `res/layout or res/layout-*` for `different device size and density`.